# Select hot articles from database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

What is the best metric to evaluate hot articles, base on views count, and created time?

I'm using `ORDER BY views_count * created_time DESC` (MySQL). I don't think it is the good idea. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

It depends of how you define a hot article, and of the frequency of article.

Another idea is to select the article created during the last day ordered by views count first, and the others ordered by created time next.